# Is refering to static Context in MainActivity from other classes bad?

Tags: java, android, static

I have developed a habit of taking a shortcut in programming, and I am wondering what the consequences are:

In MainActivity() declare:

```
 public static Context xt;
```

In the MainActivity constructor of MainActivity

```
 xt = this;
```

In my Renderer constructor:

```
 readTextFile(MainActivity.xt, R.raw.vertexcode);
```

and the function readTextFile uses context to open resources

```
public static String readTextFileFromRawResource(final Context context,
         final int resourceId)
 {
     final InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
             resourceId);
      . . .
```

Comment: By saving a `Context` in a static variable you are  creating a memory leak. Very very bad... Somehow all other answers miss that completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tavian Barnes gave you a tip use a custom Application subclass. Its my technique on android apps and working great. Activities and in-process services can use it. Application instance is a system automanaged singleton, all apps have either default or custom one. I use it for app-global things.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.my.app"
       android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="3" >

       <application
          android:name=".MyApplication"
          ...
       </application>
   </manifest>
```

**com.my.app.MyApplication**

```
package com.my.app;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override public void onCreate() {...}

    public void doSomething() {
        // getApplicationContext() getter is available here
    }
}
```

Use this getter `(MyApplication)getApplication()` in any activity or inprocess service class.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is bad, for me the bes use static variables is using Singleton.
[Singleton Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)

Now, remember if you are using reference object for the Context, probably some methods could be alter the variable, and others function can suffer the consequences.

Comment: I will give you the answer just because I didn't consider Singleton Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's "bad" mainly because there's no guarantee that your `MainActivity` constructor has been called.  This can happen if your process is terminated and then re-created while another activity is above it, for example.

You can use a custom `Application` subclass and store a static reference to its `Context` there, which will be available no matter how your app starts.  (The exception is that `ContentProvider`s may be instantiated before your `Application` subclass.)  You may want to expose it via a static method instead of a static field.

But it would be better design to simply pass the `Context` as a constructor parameter to `Renderer`, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think will be bad if your Application will lose the values of the static variables when the OS requires more memory, I use the `onResume()` method to set the value of my static variable context.

```
 public class MyApplication extends Activity{
    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
        super.onResume(); 
    }        
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I didn't know static variables values will be lost!

Comment: yes, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797187/android-static-variable-null-on-low-memory   "In your onResume() method you could query the static data to see if it is present and if not, load it back in again."

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is bad. Check Android Developers Blog.

**Avoiding memory leaks**

http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

In this case (keep Context in a static field), GC do not release Context Object until the application process is killed. This pattern is so-called memory leak and should be avoid.